# add field in customer table nopcommerce 3.3

Tags: nopcommerce

I am studying nopcommerce 3.3 and MVC 4 in also newer for me. I am learning this.
 
So I want to add new field in customer table that is `AlternateEmail`. 
I have add this field in Database then Customer model and in view but it gives me error that

> `Nop.Admin.Models.Customers.CustomerModel` does not contain a
>   definition for 'AlternateEmail` and no extension method
>   'AlternateEmail' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Nop.Admin.Models.Customers.CustomerModel' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Where I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Since version 3.30, you have custom customer attributes out of the box!

See http://www.nopcommerce.com/releasenotes.aspx:
*Allow a store owner to create custom customer attributes*

In your store, go to /Admin/Setting/CustomerUser and the "Customer form fields" tab.

Answer (score 3):

We can add new field to any entity in nopcommerce.

**step 1**

Open Customer.cs class from Nop.Core\Domain

add this line

```
public string YourProperty { get; set; }
```

**Step 2**

Open CustomerModel.cs class from Nop.Admin\Models

add above line in this class.

**Step 3**

Open CustomerController.cs from Nop.Admin\Controller

change in PrepareCustomerModel() and ActionResult Create(). add this property in this method.

**Step 4**

Open Customer table from your NopCommerce database.

Add column in this table. Provide your newly added property name same as Customer.cs in Nop.Core\Domain

Change your _CreateOrUpdate.cshtml and add new property in this page.
and run your project.

If you want to get to more detail, Click [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLlJDc0PfOAhWMrI8KHXLWDf44ChAWCE8wCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fhow-to-add-new-column-in-existing-table-in-nopcommerce&usg=AFQjCNEkDPFiH-otOP_9SaHCp9-UMwsI5w&sig2=j00kZ9povXzPnR5gnDcuMQ&bvm=bv.131783435,d.c2I)!

Answer (score 0):

We can add new field to any entity in nopcommerce.

Please note that here : 
field = column we want to add
entity = It can be any entity table name

We need to follow steps properly in order to reflect any change in any entity in nopcommerce.

Basic Steps are a follow :

1) Add Particular Column in Appropriate Table in Database
2) Change in Core Class of that entity under Nop.Core project
3) Make necessary changes in Model on that Entity
4) Initialize changed column in PrepareModel method of particular entity in entity Controller
5) Add particular field in relevant view of that entity**

I've prepared a article on my blog please follow it to resolve your problem.

[Add Custom Field In NopCommerce Table - Article](http://ajaysaksena.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/add-custom-field-in-nopcommerce-table-changes-in-admin-panel/)

Download Customer Controller Code From Here.
[CustomerContoller.cs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gze2sxrv544q77d/CustomerController.cs)

Comment: I have done all this. but my model cant fine new field.

Comment: Hi Rohi, I've uploaded CustomerContoller.cs.

Please download it and check your code.

Let me know if it worked for you. I've tested Alternate email insert/update on my machine.